# Let $\tau$ and $\rho$ be tableaus such that $\tau \leadsto \rho$. Prove that $\tau$ is satisfiable if and only if $\rho$ is satisfiable.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

I have this definition:

Let $\nu$ be any propositional interpretation. Let $b$ be any branch of a tableau. Say that $\nu$ is faithful to b if and only if for every formula, $A$, on the branch, $\nu(A)=1$

For this definition I have the following assignment:

Let $\tau$ and $\rho$ be tableaus such that $\tau \leadsto \rho$. Prove that $\tau$ is satisfiable/valid if and only if $\rho$ is satisfiable/valid.

So I suppose that $\neg(\phi \vee \psi)$ is on a branch $B$. The definition says that $\nu$ makes every formula on $B$ true. So I have:

$$\nu(\neg(\phi \vee \psi))=1$$

This means that $\tau$ is satisfied.

If we apply a rule then only one branch will occur by adding $\neg \phi$ and $\neg \psi$ to $B$. Then we see that $\nu(\neg(\phi \vee \psi))=1$ if:

$$\nu(\neg \phi)=1, \nu(\neg \psi)=1$$

And this means that $\rho$ is satisfied. Finally we can conclude that $\tau$ is satisfiable iff $\rho$ is satisfiable.

Am I correct?

Comment: I think maybe something is missing I mean like how the tableaus looks etc. But the question is stated in this way.

Comment: What does $\leadsto$ mean?

Comment: It just mean "leads to"

Comment: Does does "leads to" mean?

Comment: A tableau on the left-hand-side of $\leadsto$ can be rewritten to the tableau on the right-hand-side

Comment: This is very mysterious terminology and notation. The way I'm thinking about formalizing "leads to" as per your description, is by thinking in posets and Hasse diagrams, but then $\tau \leadsto \rho\iff \rho \leadsto \tau$, so why choose such a asymmetric symbol such as  $\leadsto$? All this is to justify my next question. What do you mean with "Can be rewritten as"?

Comment: Yes but I dont know why my teacher use this notation. I can give you a example of what I mean with "can be rewritten as" $\left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \neg \neg \phi \right\},...,B_i \right\} \ \ \ \ \leadsto \ \ \ \ \left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \phi \right\},..,B_i \right\}$

$\left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \phi \wedge \psi \right\},...,B_i \right\} \ \ \ \ \leadsto \ \ \ \ \left\{ B_1,...,B \cup \left\{ \phi, \psi \right\},...,B_i \right\}$

Comment: I hope you can figure it out

Comment: It seems to me that it means what I had in mind. But what do you mean with satisfiable tableaux?

Comment: With satisfiable I mean truth value to the propositional symbol that makes the formula true.

Comment: But a tableau isn't a formula, it's a tableau... What do you mean with tableau?

Comment: I edited my question please look above.

Comment: A branch is a finite set of formulas and a tableau is a finite set of branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proof is contained in many standard textbooks (essentially, any formal treatment of tableau).

The general idea is that if a branch $b$ of a tableau $\tau$ is satisfied by a model $M$, and any tableau rule is applied to that branch $b$ to make a new tableau $\tau'$, then there will be some branch $b'$ of $\tau'$, extending $b$, that is also satisfied by $M$.

Thus, by induction, if $\tau$ is satisfiable and $\rho$ is obtained by applying some finite sequence of rules to $\tau$, then $\rho$ is also satisfiable.

Comment: When you write "by a model $M$" does it mean that I have to make a model  by my self.

Comment: You assumed that $\tau$ was satisfiable, so you assumed you had a model satisfying every formula on some branch $b$ of $\tau$.

Comment: Carl Mummert can you please look above I edited my question.

Comment: Yes, that is the basic idea. For that direction of the proof, you just have to check all the tabelau rules.

Comment: can you elaborate on